# Границы ТТК polygon

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, polygon

не получается добавить тариф в пределах ттк.
Делал по [схеме](https://yandex.ru/blog/ymapsapi/1165),
МСК и МО работает, но ТТК нет.
Что сделал:

1. Создал ttk.json с границами ттк
2. Добавил ттк в массив tarifs, при init карты.
3. Вывел в консоль логи (Показывают, что ттк в массиве есть, но дистанция в нем 0).

Сам [сайт](http://md.ch43305.tmweb.ru/delivery.php).

Comment: А не могли бы вы поделиться полигоном для ТТК (ttk.json)?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, проблема была в Якорструкторе.
Когда делаешь экспорт многоугольника, то он почему-то меняет местами широту и долготу.

Comment: А точнее начиная с версии api 2.1 ширина и долгота указываются в обратном порядке.

Comment: Тут дело в том, что нет "правильного" порядка координат. Просто в стандарте JSON принят не тот же порядок, что используется в API по умолчанию (при подключении API можно выбрать любой порядок)